# Что за ipch в Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio

В Visual studio 2010 появилась папка ipch, а в ней файл с названием "имя_проекта_ab4cbc.ipch", у которого размер 15-20 МБ. Если отправлять исходники, то напрягает...

Кто знает - зачем он нужен и как его отключить из проекта, чтоб он не создавался?

Comment: У меня вообще больше 100 мегабайт данная паапка была. Удалил и отправил исходники, все прошло нормально[.](http://ya.ru)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Имя ipch - это сокращение от Intellisense PreCompiled Headers. Используется средствами автоподстановки Visual Studio. При отправке исходников папку можно смело удалять: она автоматически создается средой из исходников.

Я не пробовал, но если отключить Intellisense и прекомпилируемые заголовки, наверное, она не будет создаваться. Но лучше просто не обращать на нее внимание.